# What is the (relativistic) coordinate transformation between non-inertial reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, coordinate-systems

I find it best to start this question with a thought experiment. We have a rocket ship and Earth. For our purposes, Earth has no acceleration or velocity and begins at the origin. The rocket ship accelerates away from Earth with a constant acceleration $a$. This rocket ship begins at the origin ($x'_0=0$) with 0 velocity. In this thought experiment, we ignore higher order derivatives and gravity. If anything, we should derive the relativistic effects of gravity *from* the results of this thought experiment, as shown by the equivalence principle.

In my attempts to solve this so far, I have assumed that the speed of light is invariant in the accelerating reference frame (so that$x'=ct'$ here for a light pulse). Is this valid? Is acceleration (as shown in the thought experiment) absolute or relative (are both the Earth and the spaceship accelerating relative to each other or is the spaceship absolutely accelerating)? So far, here is what I have come up with in trying to solve this. Please tell me if I am wrong anywhere, what next steps I should take, and/or what conclusions I should come to:

- The Lorentz factor gamma will still be a part of this accelerating coordinate transformation, but instead of being a function of $v$, it will be a function of $at$, as that is the velocity between the reference frames (remember that $v_0$ is 0 for my initial conditions, so I never considered it for simplicity, but feel free to include it as it is important in this transformation) so that gamma takes the form $1/\sqrt{1-(at)^2/c^2}$.
- For the $x' $ transformation equation, $ x $ is unchanged, as it refers to the position of an event, and thus stays the same when acceleration is introduced to the transformation.
- For the $x' $ transformation equation, $ vt $ is integrated (I am probably using an incorrect term here, I mean that acceleration is included in the velocity), and becomes $1/2at^2+v_0^2$ (where $v_0 $ is 0 for my initial conditions). as such, the $x' $ transformation equation is $\gamma((x_{event})-(v_{frame})t-1/2(a_{frame})t^2)$.

I attempted to find the $t' $ transformation equation with these parameters and knowing that $ x'=ct' $ while $ x=ct$, but I wasn't able to solve it. What are the spacetime coordinate transformations between reference frames when one is accelerating relative to the other? How do we find them?

Answer (score 1):

> I have assumed that the speed of light is invariant in the accelerating reference frame (so that x'=ct' here for a light pulse). Is this valid?

There is no standard reference frame defined for a non-inertial observer like there is for inertial observers. There are many valid non-inertial reference frames where the speed of light is not equal to c. However, there is a class of non-inertial reference frames where the speed of light is equal to c, where the time and space coordinates are based on radar time and radar distance.

See Dolby and Gull: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0104077

> What are the spacetime coordinate transformations between reference frames when one is accelerating relative to the other? How do we find them?

The transforms are substantially more complicated than you were suggesting. The full transform is derived in the Dolby and Gull citation. In particular, you are interested in their radar coordinates in region U described in Figure 6 and the associated equations. As they derive (in natural units)
$$t’=\frac{1}{2a}\log\left(\frac{x+t}{x-t} \right)$$
$$x’=\frac{1}{2a}\log\left( a^2 x^2-a^2 t^2\right)$$

Comment: Alright, I looked at that article. Are you sure that it is technically accurate/trustworthy? I've been told that arXiv is generally untrustworthy due to reasons such as a lack of peer review. In addition, the equations reduce to 0 if a=0, regardless of coordinates. Is this because I am assuming that x_0=0 and v_0=0? Finally, the t' equation seems to imply that, due to the log function in the t' equation, as x increases, t' increases at a varying rate. This is confirmed in the article, where t' in the 'hypersurface of simultaneity' is a logarithmic function. As such, doesn't the shifting of

Comment: time proportional to space relative to an observer (shift of t' as x increases) have an exponential rate of change? This doesn't seem to make sense to me, but maybe that is just because I am used to non-accelerating special relativity. After all, space shifts at the 'same rate' as ct, and the observer is accelerating in space (the difference between x -> x' is exponential).

Comment: @Sciencemaster you are right that arxiv is not a reliable source. In fact, it should not be considered a source at all. It is simply an archival service. The source of the Dolby and Gull article is not arxiv, but rather the peer-reviewed Am.J.Phys. 69 (2001) 1257-1261. Arxiv is just a convenient place to access that source. Regarding the fact that the coordinates do not meet your expectations, you are welcome to do your own derivation. You can start with the basic radar time and distance formulas and choose your own parameterization for the accelerating observer. I encourage you to do so

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing that up. In addition, looking back, I made an error: the article states that the 'hypersurface of simultaneity' is a function of tangent, not log (which still seems counterintuitive to me, but hopefully I can accept it once I derive it.) However, the concept of radar time is new to me. I attempted to search for it online, which yielded  no results other than the same article (which is a red flag for the credibility of the article in my mind). At any rate, it just seems to be the average of the time between when a light beam is emitted and when it is received.

Comment: Another issue I take with this article that I would like to clear up is with the initial assertion that it wouldn't make sense for an event to be assigned multiple time coordinates in the accelerating reference frame and that an object 'sweeps back in time'. At first glance these seem to be very valid and intuitive properties of spacetime that need to be 'fixed'. However, it is important to note that this *only* occurs outside of an accelerating observer's light cone. More important to note however is that in the case where an observer accelerates to 'turn around', the observer...

Comment: ...only accelerates for some finite time, and then once again moves with some constant velocity, making it an inertial frame of reference. As such, it will behave as shown in the special relativistic Lorentz Transformations (in the absence of gravity) while the observer that accelerates for some time is moving with a constant velocity. As such, with enough distance (refer to the Lorentz Transformations), the 'hyperplanes of simultaneity' from before and after the acceleration will still overlap, thus assigning multiple time coordinates to the same event.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to make these 'hyperplanes of simultaneity' asymptotic even after the acceleration is 'complete', as the observer is now in an inertial reference frame. Yet this is what the article seems to claim. This would make an observer in an inertial reference frame that has once accelerated 'tainted' for lack of a better term, as with enough space, it would have to reach an asymptote to prevent an overlap, as the 'hyperplanes' are not 'parallel'. Finally, this doesn't make sense if you think of the 'hyperplanes' as connected to the reference frame rather than the observer.

Comment: This is because the reference frame should not 'remember' any acceleration, and thus the associated 'hyperplanes of simultaneity' should not behave asymptotically in *any* inertial reference frame. It simply must be consistent with the special relativistic Lorentz Transformations. Furthermore, the given transformations do not seem to approximate to the inertial Lorentz Transformations for low accelerations, especially when everything is multiplied by the acceleration (which would thus be approaching zero). Finally, these acceleration Transformations have to be similar to what is described by

Comment: Einstein's General Relativity, which these transformations might do. Maybe someone better at math than me can confirm that this is the case. At any rate, are you *sure* these transformations are accurate for an accelerating reference frame? Am I missing something here? If not, this does seem to imply the coordinate transformations for an accelerating reference frame to be different, especially when, apon further inspection, I can find nothing else on the internet that confirms these to be the correct coordinate transformations for an accelerating reference frame. Would someone please help me?

Comment: @Sciencemaster yes I am sure these are correct. They are not necessary, but they are correct. There is no standard definition of a non-inertial frame so you can choose to use coordinates that violate the second postulate. However, if you choose to use coordinates that respect the second postulate, this is the result. Regarding other sources, the article itself lists several. This approach is also known as Marzke Wheeler coordinates and is closely related to null coordinates. If you wish more discussion go to physicsforums.com where I am also active. Comments here are not meant for discussion

Comment: Alright, I apologize for any inconvenience that this may have caused. How can I discuss this further with you on the Physics Forums website (i.e. what is your username. I imagine 'Dale' is a fairly common (user)name.

Comment: @Sciencemaster user names are unique there. You can just @ Dale over there and it will alert me if I don’t see it anyway